Django POST requst post data not recived in VIEW
After the post request From  the Hrml Form view, I can't get the data from key  and values, not  able to the data form given user ,  received a  csrt_token  as a key, but I am not able to receive a key value from views , I  want o receive individual items  in the value as value, and   kes as  meta key .
**This is an HTML file **
<form action="{% url 'add_cart' single_product.id%}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token%}
        <article class="content-body">

        <h2 class="title">{{single_product.product_name}}</h2>

        <div class="mb-3"> 
            <var class="price h4">{{single_product.price}} BDT</var> 
        </div> 

        <p>{{single_product.description}}</p>


        <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item-option-select">
                    <h6>Choose Color</h6>

                    <select name="color" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        {% for i in single_product.variation_set.colors %}
                        <option value="{{ i.variation_value | lower }}">{{ i.variation_value | capfirst }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row.// -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item-option-select">
                    <h6>Select Size</h6>
                    <select name="size" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        {% for i in single_product.variation_set.sizes %}
                        <option value="{{ i.variation_value | lower }}">{{ i.variation_value | capfirst }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- row.// -->
            <hr>
            {% if single_product.stock <= 0 %}
                <h5>Out of stock </h5>
                
            {% else %}
                {% if in_cart%}
                    <a class="btn  btn-success"> <span class="text"> Added to Cart</span> <i class="fas fa-check"></i>  </a>
                    <a href="{% url 'cart'%}" class="btn  btn-outline-primary"> <span class="text">View Cart</span> <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>  </a>

                {% else %}
                    <button type = "submit" class="btn  btn-primary"> <span class="text">Add to cart</span> <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>  </button>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}

            </article> <!-- product-info-aside .// -->
</form>



def add_cart(request,product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id =product_id )
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # product_variation = []
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            value = request.POST[key]
            return HttpResponse(key+''+value)

How to get Post data on views

Dictionaries in Python have key, value pairs. If request.POST is a dict, then maybe to loop you need for k,v in request.POST.items()

You typically know which keys you want to support.
Retrieve from the request with value = request.POST.get("key name", "default value")
